# How do you dry homemade lollipops so that they are no longer sticky?

Tags: candy, drying

I made homemade lollipops and they are set, but still sticky.  How can I dry them, or what I can do so that when I wrap them they won't stick to the wrappers?

Comment: Let us know what you try and which one works best!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, drying is not necessary the option.
In general, lollipops from the industry are coated with some edible powder, like starch. This prevents the sticking part.

Answer (score 4):

In case of lollipops you want to use either sugar powder, starch or bees wax.

Answer (score 3):

You could use corn starch/corn flour, confectioners' sugar/icing sugar, or a combination of the two and just give it a light dusting.